# Find $f(y^2)$ given $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse

This seems sort of like an inverse function but I'm not sure how to find the final answer. Do I just find the inverse of $F(x)$ and then square it?

$F(x) = \frac{1}{x-8}$.

Simplify $F(y^2)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You have to surround the MathJax in `$` signs for the formatting command to work.

Comment: No, there is no inverse involved.  Can you do $F(12)$?  Can you do $F(932)$?  If so, try doing $F(y^2)$.

Comment: To answer the question, just write $y^2$ where you see $x$; don’t let it confuse you that $y$ sometimes represents $f(x)$; in this question, $y^2$ is the argument of the function

Comment: Why isn't it just $${1\over y^2-8}?$$

Comment: Okay I just use y^2 for the input that makes sense.  I was over-complicating it. Thank you everyone for your help! I reformatted the exponent but I could get the fraction to format what did you do for that @saulspatz?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Here's a tip that helped me a lot when I first came to this site.  Whenever you see a formula, you can right-click on it, and then choose "show Math As ... TeX Commands" from the popup.  That will show you the MathJax, which you can copy and paste if you like.  (You will need to surround it with `$` signs).  Try it.  Also look at the [mathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thank you--I will do that and check out the tutorial for mathJax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is like a machine that takes an input and gives an output.  The specific rules that the machine follows in order to determine the output used are presented in various ways, one of the options being how it is presented here.

$F(\color{red}x)=\dfrac{1}{\color{red}x-8}$

This means, that to get our output, we take our input (in this case $x$), and then subtract eight from it and divide 1 by the result.

We now know how to find, say, $F(\color{red}2)$ as being $F(\color{red}2)=\dfrac{1}{\color{red}2-8}$

This is the same regardless of how complicated or simple of an input we desire, be it a complicated number or even an algebraic expression.

$F(\color{red}{5.88876771}) = \dfrac{1}{\color{red}{5.88876771}-8}$

$F(\color{red}{x^2+5}) = \dfrac{1}{\color{red}{x^2+5}-8}$

Or in your case, even using a variable name different than $x$:

$F(\color{red}{y^2}) = \dfrac{1}{\color{red}{y^2}-8}$

Answer (score 0):

That should be pretty straight forward.  To go from f(x) to $f(y^2)$, replace every "x" by "$y^2$".  Here, $f(x)= \frac{1}{x- 8}$ so $f(y^2)= \frac{1}{y^2- 8}$.